# core -java Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception

The Below is a class Question which is propagating Exception handling mechanism,the desired output is Exception.Can anybody explain why the output is Exception ,Thanks in advance.

```
 Class Question {

  public void m1() throws Exception {

   try {

    m2();

   } finally {

    m3();

   }
  }
  public void m2() throws RuntimeException {

   throw new RuntimeException();

  }

  public void m3() throws Exception {

   throw new Exception();

  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   Question q = new Question();

   try {

    q.m1();

   } catch (RuntimeException re) {

    System.out.println("RuntimeException");

   } catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println("Exception");
   }
  }
```

Comment: because m1 `throws Exception`

Comment: if in finally block i call m2() method whats the output ?

Comment: if in finally block i call m2() method whats the output ? RuntimeException

Answer (score 2):

in Exception Handeling finally block will executed forcefully , no matter weather error occures in try block or not ,

here `m1()` calls `m2()` in try block , while `m2()` throw `RuntimeException` here control returning to `m1()` with `RuntimeException` but finally block will executes forcrfully before retutning a control  from try or catch block. , that's why `m3()` is called by finally Block and `m3()` throws `Exception` , here as respact to finally block `Exception` thrown by `m3()` will thrown by `m1()`. that's why you get `Exception` and `catch(Exception e)` block will going to execute.

finally block executes forcefully. As below example:

```
class Question {

  public void m1() throws Exception {

   try {


 // control forworded to finally block(if Available) before returning from try or catch block.
    return;

   } finally {

    m3();

   }
  }

  public void m3() throws Exception {

   throw new Exception();

  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   Question q = new Question();

   try {

    q.m1();

   } catch (RuntimeException re) {

    System.out.println("RuntimeException");

   } catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println("Exception");
   }
  }
```

i hope it will you help you to understand Exception Handeling and also help to solve your problems in future as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps happen as part of the program execution:

(1) `main()` calls `m1()`

(2) `m1()` method `try` block calls m2() which throws `RuntimeException`

(3) **`m1()` method `finally` block calls m3() which throws `Exception`**

(4) `Exception` will be thrown back to the caller method which is `main()`

(5) In your `main()` method `Exception` object will be caught and prints the string "Exception"

The key point is that `finally` block gets always executed even there is an `Exception` (in your code, `try` block throws `RuntimeException`) thrown by the `try` block.

> if in finally block i call m2() method whats the output ?

The output will be `RuntimeException` in this case.

Comment: not a proper answer ,Even if exception is caught or not caught finally will be called...if exception is caught by catch block it will excute catch block statement then finally block

Comment: yes, of course, `catch` block (if exists) will first and then `finally`

Answer (score 0):

> the desired output is Exception.Can anybody explain why the output is
>   Exception

Because `finally` is the last block which executed after `try`:

```
finally {
   m3();
}
```

For that you get `Exception` and not `RuntimeException`

Answer (score 0):

Because when the finally statement is executed, `m3()` is invoked and it throws `Exception`. 

So, even if a `RuntimeException` was risen before the reach of the finally statement, `RuntimeException` is not considered if the finally clause throws also another exception.

From the [14.18. The throw Statement JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html) :

> If there are any enclosing try statements (§14.20) whose try blocks
>   contain the throw statement, then any finally clauses of those try
>   statements are executed as control is transferred outward, until the
>   thrown value is caught. **Note that abrupt completion of a finally
>   clause can disrupt the transfer of control initiated by a throw
>   statement.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program execution of this question:--

.  first main() method is calling m1()

.  m1() method try block is calling m2() which throws RuntimeException

.  Then m1() method finally block is calling m3() which throws Exception

.  And Exception will be thrown back to the main()(caller method)

.  And in main() method Exception will be caught and prints.